# How to compress a string in Python to store it in Redis?

Tags: python, string, networking, compression, redis

What library or method can I use in Python so I can take a string and compress it to be stored inside of Redis?  The objective is to reduce the size of some strings (`cPickle`d objects) as they go through the wire, at the cost of some computational power.

I believe that the resulting object has to be of type `str` before storage.  I am using the [`redis-py`](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) library.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Should be able to store a byte array in redis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you [zlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html):

```
import zlib

compressedString = zlib.compress(originalString, 9)  # Compress at level 9

decompressedString = zlib.decompress(compressedString)
```

Comment: For most purposes, I'd also go with zlib. If dealing with larger strings and somewhat better compression is required, consider bz2, though it does come at the cost of more CPU cycles. A comparison can be found [here](http://log.brandonthomson.com/2011/01/quick-python-gzip-vs-bz2-benchmark.html) though YMMV.

Comment: Exaclty, zlib is kind of cheap in cpu cycles and has minimum size overhead since it doesn't store metadata.

Answer (score 3):

[Pick one](http://docs.python.org/2/library/archiving.html). bz2 is cool though.